# Присвоить результат функции с условием в C#

Tags: c#, переменные

Есть код, который обращается к функциям для получения экземпляра класса.
Функции могут ищут экземпляр в коллекции и могут вернуть сам экземпляр или null.
Если первая функция вернула null необходимо обратиться ко второй. Результат выполнения функций должен быть в переменной.

Если переменная, в которую поместили результат все равно null необходимо сообщить об этом.

Пример кода:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ObjectEvn tmp = Getobj();
        if (tmp == null) tmp = Getobj_two();

        if (tmp == null)
            Console.WriteLine("null");
        else
            Console.WriteLine(tmp.time);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static ObjectEvn Getobj()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public static ObjectEvn Getobj_two()
    {
        return new ObjectEvn();
    }

    public class ObjectEvn
    {
        public string time = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }
}
```

Можно ли упростить

```
ObjectEvn tmp = Getobj();
if (tmp == null) tmp = Getobj_two();
```

До такого вида:

```
ObjectEvn tmp = (Getobj() || Getobj_two());
```

Таким образом, что бы это было в одну строку, но и что бы функции не вызывались повторно. То есть упрощение типа

```
ObjectEvn tmp = Getobj() != null ? Getobj() : Getobj_two();
```

не подходит

Comment: _"Можно ли упростить"_ - `ObjectEvn tmp = Getobj() ?? Getobj_two();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ObjectEvn tmp = Getobj() ?? Getobj_two();

if (tmp == null)
    Console.WriteLine("null");
else
    Console.WriteLine(tmp.time);
```

Answer (score 2):

Можете попробовать возвращать через out или ref

```
var obj;
ObjectEvn tmp = Getobj(out obj) != null ? obj : Getobj_two();
```

после выполнения Getobj(out obj) в obj запишется результат.
И  далее вы его вернете. 
И не нужно заново вызывать Getobj(out obj)